# How to transfer a collection in Google Docs to a Google Apps account?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

Can I transfer a collection of docs from a private Google Docs account into a Google Apps account?

Comment: I expect that downloading the documents in a ZIP and uploading to the new account OR sharing the items with the new account and transferring ownership to the new account should be sufficient. Unfortunately, my company just _blocked_ access to Google Drive, so I can't get give a "real" answer (because I can't test it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is to either upload the files again to the Google Apps account or share the files with the Google Apps email address of yours. You cannot transfer the Ownership of the files yet (if you have upgraded Google Docs to Google Drive)- this feature will be coming shortly. If you are still using Google Docs, the owner can be changed to the Google Apps Account.

Comment: You cannot change owners across domains, so you can't change ownership from user@gmail.com user to user2@mycustomdomain.com or vice versa, aside from manually uploading.